# useEffect is triggering try catch without been called

Tags: react-native

Hello guys so i have this problem ,when i press a button a function is called and and sends an axios request so i can get some data of my books.When i recieve the data i set with useState a variable.

The problem is that useEffect is triggering without this variable been set and cacthes the try - catch so the Alert message is displaying before i even press the button.For fact its displaying in Home page when i enter the app.

The code is below :

The request

```
function boughtRentChecker(){
   //Checking if the book is Bought
   axios.post('http://*********/getBooksBought',
    {
      userID : global.id,
      bookID : bookShow.id
    }).then((response) => { 
        const data = response.data;
        console.log(data)
        setBookIsBought(data);
    })
```

```
useEffect(() => {
   
    try{
      if(bookIsBought[0].bookBought == 1){ 
        navigation.navigate('WebViewPdf',{paramKey:bookShow}) 
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert("Book is not Bought")
      }
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }  
 
  },[bookIsBought])
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will run on component mount, regardless of the useEffect dependency (see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp)), so you should have a variable to determine if its the first mount:

```js
const componentMounted = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
   if(!componentMounted.current){
     componentMounted.current = true;
     // hopefully you dont need a cleanup function
     return
   }
    try{
      if(bookIsBought[0].bookBought == 1){ 
        navigation.navigate('WebViewPdf',{paramKey:bookShow}) 
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert("Book is not Bought")
      }
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }  
 
  },[bookIsBought])
```

Or you could initialize `bookIsBought` to some default value (perhaps null or an empty object) and check that bookIsBought isnt that defaultValue:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    try{
      if(Object.keys(bookIsBought || {}).length > 0 &&
        bookIsBought[0].bookBought == 1){ 
        navigation.navigate('WebViewPdf',{paramKey:bookShow}) 
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert("Book is not Bought")
      }
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }  

  },[bookIsBought]
```

Comment: useRef is working but app feels so heavy.i dont know if it loops there all the time but the button have delay of like 2-3 seconds.I init my value but still the alert pop up displays.I cant understand whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question `useEffect` will run on every render. The execution of inside logic is dependent on the dependency array. You can restrict the `useEffect` by any bounded condition or with a dependency array to not execute the inside logic on a certain render.

One suggestion, you are using `try...catch` block directly inside a `useEffect` here. This will not bring you any desired outcome of try...catch. You can try moving the whole `try...catch` logic inside some function and call that function inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: I dont think this actual can solve the problem,its the same think but with trigerring with a function.I try it but still...im so confused